# how to access share folder from other computer by a name in xp

Tags: networking, ip-address

i want access my friends system by typing //tom in  windows RUN terminal , now i want type his full ip  like 10.233.20.23 . where i set //tom .

may i simplify my Questions.. ( **//10.233.20.23/music**  how to call by **//tom/music** )

NB : both computer in same local network. ( **in win xp** )

[image]

how to   change this to  ?????????

[image]
thanks and regards...

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the host file on your system:
[Windows]\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

With an entry like:
`10.233.20.23 tom # Toms computer`
it should work...
-> # starts a comment to describe the entry.